# Why my locally succeeded app fails on WACK after associating it with a reserved app name via store account?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I prepared a simple quiz app for Windows 8 store. My app successfully passes on WACK just after building and creating local packages without login to store account, however it fails (perf test: launch was not detected) when I login to my store account, associate the app with a reserved app name and create packages to submit.

So, I submitted my app three times and it always failed requirement 3.8 since those packages fail. What should I do? Is there anything I miss? I'm dealing with this issue for many days but I can't find the right solution.
Regards,
Hakan

---

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 1. WACK tool I use is the latest one. My Windows 8 account and Windows 8 Store account are same. However; I still have the problem.

That's what I'm doing;

I recreated my app project. Successfully builded the app and created (not store associated) app packages without login to store account on Visual Studio. After creating those packages, I started WACK on Visual Studio and app passed successfully. Then; I cleaned the solution and created the packages to upload store (I logged in to my store account on visual studio and chose the app name I reserved). After creating packages I started WACK again, but this time app failed with; "Launch was not detected" error.

I don't think there is anything else to do. I get bored after each unsuccessful submitting. What should I do? Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Requirement 3.8 is very specific, and has nothing to do with your app's name. From the [App Store Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx):

> 3.8 Your app must meet the basic performance criteria on a low-power computer
>
> - The app must launch in 5 seconds or less
> - The app must suspend in 2 seconds or less

Did you test your app on an ARM based device? How much time does your app take to start up/ suspend?

**Update:**

If you are using the standalone WACK, it is possible that you are trying to certify the old version of your application. As I recall, when you associate your app with the App Store, your app's name AND package ID change. However, bits of the old app may still be around, which can cause the certification to be run on an app that no longer exists.

Something that may help is to first uninstall your app prior to creating the package. The other thing to try is to run the certification from within Visual Studio. I have found it to be more reliable than the standalone app.

Comment: I don't have an ARM device. I tested my app on x86 2.0 GHz device (7 years old, not a powerful device) and it starts in not longer than 2 seconds. It's not a big app, just 500 KB and runs quickly.

Just before login to store account, the app passes on WACK, but when I rebuild and create the package after login to store account and associate it with the reserved app name, app fails this time. I get;   "Launch not detected" error.

Comment: @user2051173 - Are you running the certification from the standalone WACK application, or from Visual Studio? I do recall having issues with the standalone app. Visual Studio was more reliable, at least with my app.

Comment: @user2051173 - I updated my answer for some additional things to try.

Comment: I generally run WACK from Visual Studio just after creating the packages. By the way, if I submit my app package without login on Visual Studio (uploading to dashboard page directyle) do you think app can be certified?

Comment: @user2051173 - yes, this is normally how I upload my app. I upload it using the web page, and not Visual Studio.

Comment: Of course, uploding to web page is the only way. I meant creating package after login. 
Besides, I just figured out why it fails;
On Packaging tab of Package.appmanifest file; Package name changes when I associate the app with my reserved app name, and then it fails. But, if I rewrite the initial package name such as (819cfc555-5a43t ........... )  app succeeds. 
That does not make any sense, because I think I should associate the app with the reserved app name on my store account.

Comment: @user2051173 - yes, the package name changes. I mentioned this above, and recommended that you uninstall your app. Also, you must associate your app to the store. If it is not associated, it will not pass certification.

Comment: But I can't still understand, why associating the app with store causes failure although it passes before association. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user2051173 - as I mentioned above, it is possible that the old app is incomplete now (binaries no longer exist, because when you build, you are making binaries for the NEW app). However, enough bits exist that the WACK is trying to launch the OLD app. Did you try uninstalling your app?

Comment: You mean uninstalling on PC before recreating package after association? Yes I did. Also, I deleted and restarted to process on dashboard. But it's still same.
Thanks for your interest.